# Material UI - muiStaticTimePicker how can I adjust the size?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Id like to make my muiStaticTimePicker component reactive and shrink in size. I currently am displaying it in a modal and would like the clock part on top and full round clock on the bottom. Thank you !!

```
<div className={`${boxOpen ? "" : "hidden"} mb-20`} >
                <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
                  <StaticTimePicker
                    orientation="landscape"
                    slotProps={{ actionBar: { actions: [] } }}
                    onChange={handleTimeChange}
                    defaultValue={dayjs()}
                  />
                </LocalizationProvider>
              </div>
```